# How to call Assert Callback method only if all constraints are satisfied?

Tags: symfony, callback, symfony-2.1, validation

I have an entity Account with an Assert Callback method "processSignup". I would like to call "processSignup" only if login constraints and password constraints  are success. How can I check this in my processSignup method please ?

```
<?php
namespace MyProject\Bundle\FrontBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ExecutionContext;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @Assert\Callback(methods={"processSignup"})
 */
class Account
{

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Type(type="string")
     * @Assert\Length(min = 6, max = 16)
     */
    protected $login;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Type(type="string")
     * @Assert\Length(min = 8, max = 12)
     */
    protected $password;

    /**
     * @param ExecutionContext $context
     */
    public function processSignup(ExecutionContext $context)
    {
        // if login and password constraints success, do something
    }

    public function getLogin()
    {
        return $this->login;
    }

    public function setLogin($login)
    {
        $this->login = $login;
    }

    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try it with `$context->getViolations()`. It returns all violations so far

Comment: I have tried, but it returns an empty array, when the constraints are not satisfied.

Comment: You're right, but I think it's the only way to check if constraints are success or not. Try to trigger the username and password constraint and check if the array is empty or not. You can do this with Xdebug of just var_dump and die :)

Answer (score 2):

In the same case I've used validation groups:

```
/** @Assert\Callback(methods={"processSignup"}, groups={"LastValidation"}) */
class Account {
    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Type(type="string")
     * @Assert\Length(min = 6, max = 16)
     */
    protected $login;
....
}
```

and in FormType:

```
class AccountType extends AbstractType {
   public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
   {
       ....
   }

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    parent::setDefaultOptions($resolver);
    $resolver->setDefaults(
            [
            ....
            'validation_groups' => function (FormInterface $form)
                    {
                        return ['Account', 'LastValidation'];
                        // The first element's value must be the same as data-class name
                    }
            ]
    );

}
```

And then in processSignup method you can check

```
    if(0 !== $context->getViolations()->count())
    {
        return;
    }
```